# Mongoose: push value in array of objects found by a specific ID

Tags: mongoose

I want to find a program by its _id and push a value in one of the "exercice" object which I want to find by its own _id too.

Here is my model:

```js
{
    "_id": "6347c79dafed140716087cc4" // program _id,
    "title": "program 1",
    "user": "6347c67215178526c1dd403c",
    "exercices": [
        {
            "exercice": "6347c72052a0812efb3e1070",
            "totalSet": 3,
            "rest": "2mn"
            // push value here
        },
        {
            "exercice": "6347c72aa5a04e37a2bdcf71",
            "totalSet": 3,
            "rest": "2mn"
        },
    ],
    "frequency": "1 fois par semaine",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Here is what I do but it will just push a new object into exercices[]. I can't find the correct syntax to loop over exercices[] and find a specific exercice by its own _id and push value into it

```js
   const program = this.programModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      '6347c79dafed140716087cc4',
      {$push: {"exercices": { title: 'test' }}}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, need to find the related array. For this, you can use `$elemMatch` or use it like this: `'exercies.exercise' : exerciseId (your parameter)`

```js
const program = this.programModel.findOneAndUpdate
   {
     $and: [
       { _id: "6347c79dafed140716087cc4" },
       { exercices: { $elemMatch: { exercise: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(exerciseId )} } },
     ],
   },
   { $push: {"exercices.$": {title: "test"} },
   { new: true }
);
```

Also, the pushing process could be done like this if only one field will be pushed:

```js
{ $push: {"exercices.$.title": "test" }
```

Hope, it's helpful..

Comment: Thanks. Almost good. I had to add "exercices.$.custom_key" but the result will be : 

result: [{custom_key: {my_data}}]

For some reasons I can't push if there is nothing after the $..

Is it possible to push Only my data which is an object ?

Comment: if there's nothing after $. , it pushes the value inside of related object. If we want to add the object inside a key value, then need to write it's name after the $. . Can you try it without $push. Just try to add the value inside of object. Like that;         {"exercices.$": {title: "test"}} without $push

Comment: I made this process when I wanted to update the value an object inside of array. It was working. Here , the process same nearly. So, i think It may be helpful for you